# Reading memory stream

Tags: c#, stream, epplus

I'm trying to create an excel file and make that available as download. But i have some trouble with the download part.

I'm using `EPPlus` to create an xml file. I've got that working. But just local. I'm not sure how to force the download of the file.

This is my code:

```
public Stream GetXlsxDocument(IQueryable data)
{
    const string sheetName = "Sheet1";
    var localFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\test2.xlsx");
    var file = new FileInfo("test2.xlsx");
    // Used for local creation
    //ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage();
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    using (ExcelPackage p = new ExcelPackage(stream))
    {
        p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ExcelWorksheet ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        ws.Name = sheetName;
        ws.Cells.Style.Font.Size = 11;
        ws.Cells.Style.Font.Name = "Calibri";
        ws.SetValue(1, 1, "aaa"); // Test data
        // Used for local creation
        //p.SaveAs(localFile);
        p.SaveAs(stream);
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Like i said before. Creating the `xlsx` file locally on my C:\ disk works. But how can i force the download of the created `xlsx` file?

Right now its giving me an `xlsx` file of 0 bytes. I'd need to return a stream which isn't empty. Anyone any idea how i can do this..??

Comment: I think there is some missing information here. You say "download", but is this a method handler for an HTTP request? You're returning the stream (not a good idea BTW), but to whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rewind it:

```
stream.Position = 0;
return stream;
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this was all i had to do!